# Использование данных пользователя из aiogram для фильтрации в бд postgresql

Tags: python, база-данных, postgresql, aiogram

Идея состоит в том, чтобы собирать пользователей бота в одну базу данных. Бот может получать user_id, full_name и т.д.

Проблема в последней функции **new_user** и хендлере. Не понимаю как передать из aiogram значения в sql запрос для внесения в бд. Так же при выполнении кода ниже выходит ошибка:

***await DBComm.new_user()
TypeError: new_user() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'self' and 'conn'***

```
class DBComm:
    async def run(self):
        conn = await asyncpg.connect(database="members", user="postgres", password="1234", host="127.0.0.1",
                                     port="5432")
        return conn

    async def select(self, conn):
        values = await conn.fetchrow('SELECT * FROM users')
        a = dict(values)
        data = [f"{k}-{v}" for k, v in values.items()]
        # print(data)
        text = "\n".join(data)
        # print(text)
        return text

    async def new_user(self, conn, use=True):
        user = types.User.get_current()
        user_id = user.id
        full_name = user.full_name
        args = (user_id, use, full_name)
        await conn.execute('INSERT INTO users (user_id, use, full_name) VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING id', args)


@dp.message_handler(commands="s", state="*")
async def user(message: types.message):
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    full_name = message.from_user.full_name
    await DBComm.new_user()
    await message.answer('test')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

не приходилось работать с `aiogram`, но могу предоставить пример с `pytelegrambotapi`:

```
def create_db_users(id_tlgrm, phone_tlgrm):
    conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname=db_name, user=db_user, password=db_password, host=db_host)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO users VALUES (%s, %s);", (id_tlgrm, phone_tlgrm))
    conn.commit()


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['contact'])
def contact_phone(message):
    create_db_users(message.chat.id, message.contact.phone_number)
```

А указанная ошибка

> await DBComm.new_user() TypeError: new_user() missing 2 required
> positional arguments: 'self' and 'conn'

говорит о том, что вы не передали `self` и `conn` в функцию в месте, где вы её вызываете.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка в том, что Вы не вызвали метод `DBComm().run()`, перед тем как создавать нового пользователя.

```py
@dp.message_handler(commands="s", state="*")
async def user(message: types.message):
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    full_name = message.from_user.full_name
    conn = await DBComm().run()

    await DBComm().new_user(conn=conn)
    await message.answer('test')
```